How do I get the Transparent Background to appear transparent, not black using emission shaders?

I am attempting to use a png but I want it to light up. I've accomplished this however the transparent background is showing up black. How do I correct this?

I'm not sure what your Light Path is for but if you want transparency mix your current setup with a Transparent node and use the Alpha output of your image as factor in the Mix Shader:


PERFECT! Thank you!
